# Trying to arrange <LI> and feeling very stuck

Tags: html, css

**Problem:** I have to arrange these LI in a very specific way. Here is the image:

[image: Here is the image]

but I can't seem to break the boxes up. I have tried Flexbox, ClearFix, etc... no luck.

Please look at the picture so you can see how I am suppose to make this look.

```css
* {

    box-sizing: border-box;
}


a {
    color: #777777;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;

}


#wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 960px;
}

.contentBox {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: #dddddd;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: .01em;
}

#firstName {
    color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #4aaaa5;
    width: 300px;
    height: 85px;
    float: left;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    line-height: 250%;
    text-align: center;
}


#menu {
    color: #777777;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 300px;
    height: 85px;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    float: right;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;

}


hr {
    clear: both;
    border-width: .03em;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    align-self: center;
    border-color: #777777;
}


#backgroundTest {
    background-image: url(https://grobconnolly.github.io/myportfolio/assets/images/swirl_pattern.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    padding: 70px;
    height: calc(100% - 87px);
}


#portfolioWrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: #dddddd;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: .01em;
}

.contentHeading {
    clear: both;
    color: #4aaaa5;
    margin: 15px 0 15px 15px;
}

.grayLine {
    margin: 15px auto;
    color: #777777;
    width: 930px;
    border-width: 1px;
    align-self: center;
}

#footerBox {
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #666666;
    height: 4rem;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #4aaaa5;
    border-top-width: 10px;
    align-self: center;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

}

#copyright {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#robImage {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
}

p {
    color: #777777;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    word-spacing: 3px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5;

}


#footerLine {
    color: #4aaaa5;
}


#cr1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* contact us page CSS */

#contentPadding {
    background-image: url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/MtzMSUjbfaDQY8xgppp8r826LVuwgwCkTE9aMTfPdHC5OUWr5UcBB4ulo1O_mzdaC6MAkzeN9G_11dSYYZCNfUM1lZKQW9xOfO3gDmeGi9ZW8FysGaSUoRqUctnzDBxjPUu2CF7GbOVdn8WOQviSnopCBSrqraAm0CFro5iQSvor-a513LA2Q4eCi88oB5PIZmJxn_av7T0kHVngc5BNKykQJNR13g4kep_BcaN_YbTrqAZBYfMy2FdD0klkUoQbLshgItmWQ6gH-Q-Ef3gjC0kLbxJBF4nTJJAJ027dahF-Cv_scyWwDDSxS4nNqQ4vsdFahevNFQItM94j8938kSyzw-99t3Ss6K7jo4YmV8Q8ixY5CCuL7-syMcbz6bJ3AMOOth2qjon9IQqr0fao4jqLQaMLK0I2bE8PcTHNISWz95VFiWOYnCxo76YOoClTl4zCO8obfxbo9TKdClhyjxYZ6BmSosFxGhd59YPcmdFmRIO18Vei4PBUyKK8pTPLwixUuG9AEkpljz-A7URK5AZxbUT_VlWBdqZWPbf8kaiiX24eY10BP15A-57I1AeVEuNlV61OsC2xr43YSf3M8-xYb2k1wqsWIE0mocY-L8h_jb8RCISwHmSlwNWGEiVGMvFHpsktw0szLV0UzRydDma0S9tisXJfiQPRzWxFc4aRfyJ2PQmg=s400-no");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    padding: 70px;
    height: 100%;
}

/* Style inputs with type="text", select elements and textareas */
input[type=text],
select,
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    /* Full width */
    padding: 12px;
    /* Some padding */
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    /* Gray border */
    border-radius: 4px;
    /* Rounded borders */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* Make sure that padding and width stays in place */
    margin-top: 6px;
    /* Add a top margin */
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    /* Bottom margin */
    resize: vertical
        /* Allow the user to vertically resize the textarea (not horizontally) */
}

/* Style the submit button with a specific background color etc */
input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #4aaaa5;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* When moving the mouse over the submit button, add a darker green color */
input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #4aaaa5;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* Add a background color and some padding around the form */

.container {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: #cccccc;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 20px;
    align-self: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #777777;
}


/* start of portfolio css */

/*
#boxClass {
    
    display: flex;
    width: 540px;
    height: 800px;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-align: center; */


#boxTitleHangman {
    list-style: none;
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px 15px 30px 15px;
    background-size: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(https://grobconnolly.github.io/myportfolio/assets/images/hangman.jpg);
    }

#hangmanText {
    background: #4aaaa5;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    right: 15px;
    line-height: 40px;
    }



#boxTitleTrivia {
    list-style: none;
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px 15px 30px 15px;
    background-size: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(https://grobconnolly.github.io/myportfolio/assets/images/trivia.jpg);
    }

#triviaText {
    background: #4aaaa5;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    right: 15px;
    line-height: 40px;
    }

#boxTitleRock {
    list-style: none;
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px 15px 30px 15px;
    background-size: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(https://grobconnolly.github.io/myportfolio/assets/images/rps.jpg);
}

#rockText {
    background: #4aaaa5;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    right: 15px;
    line-height: 40px;

    }

#boxTitleRpg {
    list-style: none;
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px 15px 30px 15px;
    background-size: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(https://grobconnolly.github.io/myportfolio/assets/images/rpg.jpg);
}
#rpgText {
    background: #4aaaa5;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    right: 15px;
    line-height: 40px;
    }


#boxTitleRutgers {
    list-style: none;
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px 15px 30px 15px;
    background-size: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(https://grobconnolly.github.io/myportfolio/assets/images/rutgers.jpg);
}

#rutgersText {
    background: #4aaaa5;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    right: 15px;
    line-height: 40px;
    }


.portfolioTitle {
    background: #4aaaa5;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    right: 15px;
    line-height: 40px;
    }

#hangmanBackground {
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px 15px 30px 15px;
    background-size: 100%;
    float: left;
}

#triviaBackground {
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px 15px 30px 15px;
    background-size: 100%;
    float: left;
}

#rockBackground {
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px 15px 30px 15px;
    background-size: 100%;
    float: left;
}

#rpgBackground {

    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px 15px 30px 15px;
    background-size: 100%;
    float: left;
}

#rutgersBackground {
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px 15px 30px 15px;
    background-size: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Rob Connolly's Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">

</head>

<body>

    <!-- this div contains the header-->
    <div id="wrap">

        <header>
            <!-- name in header-->
            <h1 id="firstName">
                Rob Connolly
            </h1>
        </header>
        <!-- Header-->
        <div id="menu">

            <span>
                <a href="./index.html">About</a>
            </span>

            <span>
                <a href="./portfolio.html"> Portfolio</a>
            </span>

            <span>
                <a href="./contact.html">Contact</a>
            </span>


        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- clear fix cleard float-->
    <hr id="clearfix">

    <!-- background image-->
    <div id="backgroundTest">

        <!-- Wrap2 wraps portfolio content section-->
        <div class="contentBox">

            <!-- Portfolio Heading-->
            <h2 class="contentHeading">
                Portfolio
            </h2>
            <!-- gray line in about me section-->
            <hr class="grayLine">

            <!-- Portfolio Form-->



            <ul id="boxList">

                <li id="boxTitleHangman">
                    <p id="hangmanText">
                        Hangman
                    </p>
                </li>

                <li id="boxTitleTrivia">
                    <p id="triviaText">
                        Trivia
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li id="boxTitleRock">
                    <p id="rockText">
                        Rock
                    </p>
                </li>

                <li id="boxTitleRpg">
                    <p id="rpgText">
                        Rpg
                    </p>
                </li>

                <li id="boxTitleRutgers">
                    <p id="rutgersText">
                        Rutgers
                    </p>
                </li>

            </ul>

            <!-- 
                <div id="hangman">
                <div id="hangmanBackground" style="background-image: url('assets/images/hangman.jpg');">
                    <p class="portfolioTitle">Hangman</p>
                </div>

                <div id="trivia">
                    <div id="triviaBackground" style="background-image: url('assets/images/trivia.jpg');">
                        <p class="portfolioTitle">Trivia Game</p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="rock">
                        <div id="rockBackground" style="background-image: url('assets/images/rps.jpg');">
                            <p class="portfolioTitle">Rock Paper Scissors</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="row2">
                        <div id="rpg">
                            <div id="rpgBackground" style="background-image: url('assets/images/rpg.jpg');">
                                <p class="portfolioTitle">RPG Game</p>
                            </div>

                            <div id="rutgers">
                                <div id="rutgersBackground" style="background-image: url('assets/images/rutgers.jpg');">
                                    <p class="portfolioTitle">Rutgers Info Widget</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                </div> -->

            <!-- Start of footer-->
            <div id="footerBox">
                <!-- Text for footer-->
                <p id="cr1"> &copy; Copyright</p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you really need them to be LI's? This could simply be done with divs.

Comment: @JerdineSabio it doesn't matter if it's `<li>` or `<div>` element, all can be styled the same way. LI might be better semantically.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the id you have given the `<ul>` tag i.e boxlist and then apply the display as flex this way all your li elements will be in a flex box.Then work with the `<li>` elements as flex box elements here is a link that could help you out:-

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

I would highly recommend you to use grid as it can be more usefull and I like it better than flex box,here is the link you can use to refer how a grid box is used:-

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, Its simple use `column-count:` property on `ul`

Here is updated snippet.

```css
* {

    box-sizing: border-box;
}


a {
    color: #777777;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;

}


#wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 960px;
}

.contentBox {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: #dddddd;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: .01em;
}
#firstName {
    color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #4aaaa5;
    width: 300px;
    height: 85px;
    float: left;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    line-height: 250%;
    text-align: center;
}


#menu {
    color: #777777;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 300px;
    height: 85px;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    float: right;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;

}


hr {
    clear: both;
    border-width: .03em;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    align-self: center;
    border-color: #777777;
}


#backgroundTest {
    background-image: url(https://grobconnolly.github.io/myportfolio/assets/images/swirl_pattern.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    padding: 70px;
    height: 100vh;
}


#portfolioWrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: #dddddd;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: .01em;
}

.contentHeading {
    clear: both;
    color: #4aaaa5;
    margin: 15px 0 15px 15px;
}
#boxList{
column-count: 2;
}

.grayLine {
    margin: 15px auto;
    color: #777777;
    width: 930px;
    border-width: 1px;
    align-self: center;
}

#footerBox {
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #666666;
    height: 4rem;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #4aaaa5;
    border-top-width: 10px;
    align-self: center;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

}

#copyright {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#robImage {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
}

p {
    color: #777777;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    word-spacing: 3px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5;

}


#footerLine {
    color: #4aaaa5;
}


#cr1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* contact us page CSS */

#contentPadding {
    background-image: url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/MtzMSUjbfaDQY8xgppp8r826LVuwgwCkTE9aMTfPdHC5OUWr5UcBB4ulo1O_mzdaC6MAkzeN9G_11dSYYZCNfUM1lZKQW9xOfO3gDmeGi9ZW8FysGaSUoRqUctnzDBxjPUu2CF7GbOVdn8WOQviSnopCBSrqraAm0CFro5iQSvor-a513LA2Q4eCi88oB5PIZmJxn_av7T0kHVngc5BNKykQJNR13g4kep_BcaN_YbTrqAZBYfMy2FdD0klkUoQbLshgItmWQ6gH-Q-Ef3gjC0kLbxJBF4nTJJAJ027dahF-Cv_scyWwDDSxS4nNqQ4vsdFahevNFQItM94j8938kSyzw-99t3Ss6K7jo4YmV8Q8ixY5CCuL7-syMcbz6bJ3AMOOth2qjon9IQqr0fao4jqLQaMLK0I2bE8PcTHNISWz95VFiWOYnCxo76YOoClTl4zCO8obfxbo9TKdClhyjxYZ6BmSosFxGhd59YPcmdFmRIO18Vei4PBUyKK8pTPLwixUuG9AEkpljz-A7URK5AZxbUT_VlWBdqZWPbf8kaiiX24eY10BP15A-57I1AeVEuNlV61OsC2xr43YSf3M8-xYb2k1wqsWIE0mocY-L8h_jb8RCISwHmSlwNWGEiVGMvFHpsktw0szLV0UzRydDma0S9tisXJfiQPRzWxFc4aRfyJ2PQmg=s400-no");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    padding: 70px;
    height: 100%;
}

/* Style inputs with type="text", select elements and textareas */
input[type=text],
select,
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    /* Full width */
    padding: 12px;
    /* Some padding */
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    /* Gray border */
    border-radius: 4px;
    /* Rounded borders */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* Make sure that padding and width stays in place */
    margin-top: 6px;
    /* Add a top margin */
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    /* Bottom margin */
    resize: vertical
        /* Allow the user to vertically resize the textarea (not horizontally) */
}

/* Style the submit button with a specific background color etc */
input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #4aaaa5;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* When moving the mouse over the submit button, add a darker green color */
input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #4aaaa5;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* Add a background color and some padding around the form */

.container {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: #cccccc;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 20px;
    align-self: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #777777;
}


/* start of portfolio css */

/*
#boxClass {
    
    display: flex;
    width: 540px;
    height: 800px;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-align: center; */


#boxTitleHangman {
    list-style: none;
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px 15px 30px 15px;
    background-size: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(https://grobconnolly.github.io/myportfolio/assets/images/hangman.jpg);
    }

#hangmanText {
    background: #4aaaa5;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    right: 15px;
    line-height: 40px;
    }



#boxTitleTrivia {
    list-style: none;
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px 15px 30px 15px;
    background-size: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(https://grobconnolly.github.io/myportfolio/assets/images/trivia.jpg);
    }

#triviaText {
    background: #4aaaa5;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    right: 15px;
    line-height: 40px;
    }

#boxTitleRock {
    list-style: none;
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px 15px 30px 15px;
    background-size: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(https://grobconnolly.github.io/myportfolio/assets/images/rps.jpg);
}

#rockText {
    background: #4aaaa5;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    right: 15px;
    line-height: 40px;

    }

#boxTitleRpg {
    list-style: none;
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px 15px 30px 15px;
    background-size: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(https://grobconnolly.github.io/myportfolio/assets/images/rpg.jpg);
}
#rpgText {
    background: #4aaaa5;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    right: 15px;
    line-height: 40px;
    }


#boxTitleRutgers {
    list-style: none;
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px 15px 30px 15px;
    background-size: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(https://grobconnolly.github.io/myportfolio/assets/images/rutgers.jpg);
}

#rutgersText {
    background: #4aaaa5;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    right: 15px;
    line-height: 40px;
    }


.portfolioTitle {
    background: #4aaaa5;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    right: 15px;
    line-height: 40px;
    }

#hangmanBackground {
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px 15px 30px 15px;
    background-size: 100%;
    float: left;
}

#triviaBackground {
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px 15px 30px 15px;
    background-size: 100%;
    float: left;
}

#rockBackground {
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px 15px 30px 15px;
    background-size: 100%;
    float: left;
}

#rpgBackground {

    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px 15px 30px 15px;
    background-size: 100%;
    float: left;
}

#rutgersBackground {
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px 15px 30px 15px;
    background-size: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Rob Connolly's Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">

</head>

<body>

    <!-- this div contains the header-->
    <div id="wrap">

        <header>
            <!-- name in header-->
            <h1 id="firstName">
                Rob Connolly
            </h1>
        </header>
        <!-- Header-->
        <div id="menu">

            <span>
                <a href="./index.html">About</a>
            </span>

            <span>
                <a href="./portfolio.html"> Portfolio</a>
            </span>

            <span>
                <a href="./contact.html">Contact</a>
            </span>


        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- clear fix cleard float-->
    <hr id="clearfix">

    <!-- background image-->
    <div id="backgroundTest">

        <!-- Wrap2 wraps portfolio content section-->
        <div class="contentBox">

            <!-- Portfolio Heading-->
            <h2 class="contentHeading">
                Portfolio
            </h2>
            <!-- gray line in about me section-->
            <hr class="grayLine">

            <!-- Portfolio Form-->



            <ul id="boxList">

                <li id="boxTitleHangman">
                    <p id="hangmanText">
                        Hangman
                    </p>
                </li>

                <li id="boxTitleTrivia">
                    <p id="triviaText">
                        Trivia
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li id="boxTitleRock">
                    <p id="rockText">
                        Rock
                    </p>
                </li>

                <li id="boxTitleRpg">
                    <p id="rpgText">
                        Rpg
                    </p>
                </li>

                <li id="boxTitleRutgers">
                    <p id="rutgersText">
                        Rutgers
                    </p>
                </li>

            </ul>

            <!-- 
                <div id="hangman">
                <div id="hangmanBackground" style="background-image: url('assets/images/hangman.jpg');">
                    <p class="portfolioTitle">Hangman</p>
                </div>

                <div id="trivia">
                    <div id="triviaBackground" style="background-image: url('assets/images/trivia.jpg');">
                        <p class="portfolioTitle">Trivia Game</p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="rock">
                        <div id="rockBackground" style="background-image: url('assets/images/rps.jpg');">
                            <p class="portfolioTitle">Rock Paper Scissors</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="row2">
                        <div id="rpg">
                            <div id="rpgBackground" style="background-image: url('assets/images/rpg.jpg');">
                                <p class="portfolioTitle">RPG Game</p>
                            </div>

                            <div id="rutgers">
                                <div id="rutgersBackground" style="background-image: url('assets/images/rutgers.jpg');">
                                    <p class="portfolioTitle">Rutgers Info Widget</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                </div> -->

            <!-- Start of footer-->
            <div id="footerBox">
                <!-- Text for footer-->
                <p id="cr1"> &copy; Copyright</p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Gridview**

```
<ul class="gridview grid-3">
    <li><p>Hello<br>Hello</p></li>
    <li><p>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello</p></li>
    <li><p>Hello</p></li>
    <li><p>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello</p></li>
    <li><p>Hello</p></li>
    <li><p>Hello<br>Hello</p></li>
    <li><p>Hello</p></li>
    <li><p>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello</p></li>
    <li><p>Hello</p></li>
    <li><p>Hello<br>Hello</p></li>
</ul>
```

```
ul.gridview > li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.gridview > li p {
    background: #ddd;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Grid-3 */
ul.grid-3 > li {
    width: calc(100% / 3 - 2 * 10px / 3);
}
ul.grid-3 > li:nth-child(n + 4) {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
ul.grid-3 > li:nth-child(3n + 1) {
    clear: left;
}
ul.grid-3 > li:not(:nth-child(3n + 1)) {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

/* Grid-4 */
ul.grid-4 > li {
    width: calc(100% / 4 - 3 * 10px / 4);
}
ul.grid-4 > li:nth-child(n + 5) {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
ul.grid-4 > li:nth-child(4n + 1) {
    clear: left;
}
ul.grid-4 > li:not(:nth-child(4n + 1)) {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/vanquyet/pen/xxbgoZd)